# How to build HIDAPI library in release mode on Linux?

Tags: linux, makefile, release, autotools, hidapi

I am trying to create a stripped `.so` file for the HIDAPI library. I cloned the library from https://github.com/libusb/hidapi.git. I followed the steps for building on a Linux system:

```
./bootstrap
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

It is generating the `.so` file at given location. When I checked the `.so` file with file-command, I am getting "not-stripped".

```
$ file libhidapi-libusb.so.0.0.0
libhidapi-libusb.so.0.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=df7b02a51941902793e795cd5ff7ec3173d3a7fe, with debug_info, not stripped
```

How can I generate the `.so` file of the HIDAPI library in Release mode for Linux?

Answer (score 1):

> How to build HIDAPI library in release mode on Linux?

Release mode typically means (1) optimizations at `-O2` or `-O3`, and (2) debug asserts are removed. For (2) you typically define `-DNDEBUG`. So your `CPPFLAGS` should include `-DNDEBUG`; and your `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` should include `-O2` or `-O3`.

Release builds may (or may not) strip symbols. There's not much use in stripping symbols in a public library. It makes more sense to strip symbols in a closed source/private binary. Usually you *do not* want to strip because stripping makes stack traces useless.

With that said, the standard GNU Make target to strip binaries is `make install-strip`; see [16.6 Standard Targets for Users](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html) in the GNU Make manual. And note from the manual:

> `install-strip` should not strip the executables in the build
>   directory which are being copied for installation. It should only
>   strip the copies that are installed.

Also note that shared objects have to export public symbols, so you may not remove as many symbols as you expect. You might also be interested in [Symbol Visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) on the GCC wiki.

---

> How can I generate the .so file of the HIDAPI library in release mode for Linux?

To summarize, build with:

- `CPPFLAGS` should include `-DNDEBUG`
- `CFLAGS` should include `-O2` or `-O3`
- `CXXFLAGS` should include `-O2` or `-O3`

And install with:

- `make install-strip`

Comment: I note that the GNU `make` documentation about the `install-strip` target is of course a *recommendation*.  It is up to the makefile creator to actually provide such a target, and many do not do so.  Inasmuch as the question is tagged [autotools], however, it is relevant that Automake does provide `install-strip` targets, as one would expect from a component of the GNU build system.